# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am new to firebase and am trying to use firebase authenticator. Currently I have 2 dart files - main.dart and user.dart.

In user.dart below, I am facing this issue with null safety.

[image]

On the last line, I am facing the error: A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'User' in a const constructor.

So to resolve this, I decided to change line 7 to `final User? data;` which resolved the issue. However, the problem now arises in my main.dart file.

Here is a snapshot of my main.dart
[image]

On line 25, I receive the error: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'.

So to fix this, I decided to change line 25 to `(user) => CurrentUser.create(user!),` . Adding the '!'

When I run my code now, I receive this exception:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<User?, CurrentUser> listened by
StreamProvider<CurrentUser>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
Null check operator used on a null value

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Can someone please explain what is going on and how I can solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the field `data` in the class `CurrentUser` as nullable, of type `User?`, you also have to change the line 12 of your class, by setting the parameter received by the factory method `create()` as `User?`.

Like this:

```
factory CurrentUser.create(User? data){
  return CurrentUser._(data, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting these compile-time errors since you're trying to explicitly set a NON-NULLABLE variable to `null`, directly in a constructor.

Another thing that's worth mentioning is the use of the `!` operator in your case. When you use the `!` operator you're telling Dart that you, as the developer, are taking responsibility in making sure that the variable is not `null`. Therefore, since the variable you're passing is indeed `null`, a run-time error is thrown.

All of your implementation can be drastically simplified once you understand null safety. For example the `isInitialValue` parameter can be easily get rid of.

Take a good read at [Dart's Sound Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) documentation to understand so.

Answer (score 0):

make your variable is nullable or add ! to your user variable to check null